# Select Where Query sqlite and Qt

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I want to find a word in all record of a column base on QlinEedit::textChanged. .

```
connect(ui->PoemSrch, &QLineEdit::textChanged, this, &MainWindow::updateTextPoem);


void MainWindow::updateTextPoem(const QString & st){
foreach (const QStringList &var, lst) {
    qDebug() << var.filter(st);
    QSqlQueryModel * modal1 = new QSqlQueryModel();
    QSqlQuery qry;
    qry.prepare("select * from Poems where Poem like ?");
    qry.addBindValue(QString("%1%").arg(st));
    modal1->setQuery(qry);
    ui->tableView->setModel(modal1);
 }
}
```

Comment: Look into the various FTS (Full Text Search) modules that are part of sqlite.

Comment: @Shawn If it's possible answer question. I didn't understand.

Comment: I want after it finds word in poem text update tableView with all columns

Answer (score 0):

```
 void MainWindow::updateTextPoem(const QString & st)
{
    QSqlQuery query("SELECT * FROM Poems where Poem like '%' || ? || '%'");
    query.addBindValue(QString("%1%").arg(st));
    QSqlQueryModel * modal = new QSqlQueryModel();
    query.exec();
    modal->setQuery(query);
    ui->tableView->setModel(modal);
}
```